# Windows 7 64 bit not booting with Intel iMac (Mid-2007 model)

Tags: windows, 64-bit, boot-camp

I have an Intel iMac, Mid-2007 model or MB878LL and I'm unable to load the 64 bit DVD I downloaded from TechNet for Windows 7.

I read here http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1846 that 64 bit Vista is only supported on select Macs.

Is this true?  Is there (until Snow Lepard launch) no support for 64 bit Windows 7 on my machine?  Is this a boot camp limitation or just Apple trying to force me to upgrade?

If this isn't possible, I think it's a terrible waste if you ask me.

Or, has anyone been able to get this to work, and be stable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's a good bet that if 64 Vista isn't supported than 64 7 won't be either.

Comment: 64 bit Operating Systems are not supported on the iMac in Boot Camp. Been there, tried that, I get a lovely error.

Comment: @EvilChookie: Yea, you get two options and blinking prompt you can't type into.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can, and here is the blog post detailing how!

[Windows Vista x64](http://jowie.com/blog/post/2008/02/24/Select-CD-ROM-Boot-Type-prompt-while-trying-to-boot-from-Vista-x64-DVD-burnt-from-iso-file.aspx) and here is the addendum for [Windows 7 x64](http://simpable.com/software/mbp-64bit-vista/)