# iMac 20" Intel - Win7 Install Does Not Support Bootcamp 64-bit?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, boot-camp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Windows 7 64 bit not booting with Intel iMac (Mid-2007 model)](https://superuser.com/questions/25765/windows-7-64-bit-not-booting-with-intel-imac-mid-2007-model)

#### The Scenario

I have a 20"Intel iMac running OSX Leopard.
The computer was dual booted using bootcamp to run win xp 32-bit.
I have just erased this partition and installed Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit.
When I insert my leopard disk to install bootcamp drivers it fails with the error message:

'Version Does Not Support 64-bit Bootcamp'

#### However

I also have a brand new MacBook Pro running Snow Leopard.
I was able to partition the hardrive on the MacBook and install a copy of Windows 7 evaluation version and then install bootcamp drivers from the Snow Leopard disk.

#### Question 1

I can't understand why the iMac cannot install the 64bit drivers from the leopard disk, is this because Leopard is not full 64-bit?

#### Question 2

Is the reason that the MacBook can support the snow leopard 64-bit drivers to do with the fact that it is running an evaluation copy of windows 7?

#### Question 3

If I upgrade the iMac to Snow Leopard will I then be able to install the bootcamp 64-bit drivers on that copy of Windows 7 Ultimate?
Will I have to completely reinstall windows 7 ultimate in order for windows to recognise the snow leopard upgrade to full 64-bit?

#### Very Confused

Help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just to quote [from a previous question on this](https://superuser.com/questions/25765/windows-7-64-bit-not-booting-with-intel-imac-mid-2007-model):

> [Microsoft Windows Vista 64-bit](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1846)
>   editions work with certain Intel-based
>   Mac computers via Boot Camp, which is
>   included with Mac OS X v10.5 Leopard.

So it's most likely not supported for you iMac.

But according to [Chris](https://superuser.com/users/6605/chris) you can:

> Actually you can, and here is the blog
>   post detailing how!
>
> [Windows Vista x64](http://jowie.com/blog/post/2008/02/24/Select-CD-ROM-Boot-Type-prompt-while-trying-to-boot-from-Vista-x64-DVD-burnt-from-iso-file.aspx) and here is the
>   addendum for [Windows 7 x64](http://simpable.com/software/mbp-64bit-vista/)

This might not answer all your questions, but it does explain why you're having problems. I guess the answers would be: No, No and No...